# I have a pandas dataframe and I need to get the mode of a groupby object. It was working but it's suddenly not

Tags: python, pandas

I really hope someone can help with this, it was working but now it is suddenly not and I can't work out why. Consider the following:

```
def generate_mode(option):
    averages_text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    if option == 'Large Airport':
        df = data.query('type_airport_large_airport == 1')
        mode = df.groupby('type_airport_large_airport')['frequency_mhz'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
        averages_text.insert('1.0', 'The mode for large airport is {}'.format(mode.iat[0]))
    
    elif option == 'Frequency':
        freq_data = data.query('frequency_mhz > 100')
        mode = freq_data['frequency_mhz'].mode()
        averages_text.insert('1.0', 'The mode for frequency over 100mhz is {}'.format(mode.iat[0]))
```

This line:

```
mode = df.groupby('type_airport_large_airport')['frequency_mhz'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

Throws an error:

```
ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
```

if I change the option to .agg(pd.Series.median) it works fine.

Can anyone see what could be happening?

Comment: `pd.Series.mode()` always returns `pd.Series` since multiple modes are possible. `agg()` method is expecting some value (int, str, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Boris, `pd.Series.mode()` always returns a `pd.Series` (which is kinda an indexed list). A workaround for this would be:

```py
df.groupby('type_airport_large_airport')['frequency_mhz'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
```

to capture the first element of the returned values (first mode). When using this approach, it's important to keep in mind that `PD.Series.mode()` returns all elements when there's no mode (so we'll capture the first value anyways), and if there are two or more modes, it'll show only the first one.